# When an infinite lattices is algebraic?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-orders

I'm reading some books on lattices. Well, I met the notions of compact elements of a lattice and algebraic lattices. The former are the elements $c$ such that for every directed subset D of L, if D has a supremum $\sup D$ and $c \ge \sup D$ then $c \ge d$ for some element $d$ of $D$; while the latter are the lattices in which every element is the supremum of the compact elements below.
Now, if we consider a finite lattice, then it is algebraic. What about the infinite case?
Can you also suggest me some books and papers investigating the topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me modify your definition slightly. Algebraic lattices are: *the **complete** lattices in which every element is the supremum of the compact elements below.* The set of integers under the usual order have the property that every element is the supremum of the compact elements below, but $\mathbb Z$ is not algebraic.

The natural examples of algebraic lattices are the lattices of closed subsets of an algebraic closure operator, e.g. any subalgebra lattice of an algebraic structure. A simple example of an infinite lattice that is not algebraic is the unit interval $[0,1]$ of the real line under the usual order.

For a short introduction to algebraic lattices, try  [JB Nation's notes.](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~jb/math618/os3uh.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

There are also infinite algebraic lattices. For example, the free lattice generated by a set of chains, $FL(2+2)$, defined [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103039900), is infinite, finitely-generated, bounded and algebraic.